# Calling an alert function from a button but without using onclick

Tags: javascript, html

What im trying to do, is to call my function from whenever someone clicks on my button. However, i know that it can be done with

```
<button onclick="myFuntion()>
```

But i want to skip that step, i dont want a function in my button, i've heard that its bad programming.

However, heres how my file looks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javacript" src="javascript.js"> </script>
<title> Javascript </title>

<script>

function testFunction(){
document.getElementById("test").onclick = Hello;
}
function Hello(){
    alert("Hello");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" id="test" <!-- I know i can use onclick="testFunction()" here but i dont wanna !-->> Click me </button>

</body>

</html>
```

So how come it doesnt pop-up with the box "Hello" whenever i push the button, what have I done wrong?

Comment: So you don't want to attach the function to the click event, and you're asking why it doesn't run the function when you click it?  That's what the click event is *for*.  It's not really clear what the problem is here.

Comment: Well you never call testFunction anywhere so the click event is not added to the button.

Comment: The question is: Why don't use onclick that is designed for do this?

Comment: You appear to have read somewhere that putting `script` elements in the `head` is a good thing. It isn't. Unless you have a very good reason to do something else, `script` elements go in the `body`, at the very end, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 5):

You have to call your `testFunction` after the HTML body is loaded so that it actually creates he binding.

That is, at the end of the file, you'd do something like:

```html
...
<script>
   testFunction()
</script>
</body>
...
```

If you run that binding code in your `head` script the `button` element won't exist yet — that is why this have to be at the end.

JavaScript libraries such as jQuery make this more elegant by providing an  `ready` hook, where one puts code to be called once the page is fully loaded, without having to resort to code on the bottom of the page.

Complete example with `script` at end *(confusingly, Stack Snippets don't show it to you in the order they actually are in the snippet; even though it doesn't look like it, the script is at the end here)*:

```js
// Scoping function to avoid creating unnecessary globals
(function() {
  // The click handler
  function Hello() {
    alert("Hello");
  }

  // Hooking it up -- you *can* do it like you did:
  //document.getElementById("test").onclick = Hello;
  // ...but the modern way is to use addEventListener,
  // which allows for more than one handler:
  document.getElementById("test").addEventListener(
    "click", Hello, false
  );
})();
```

```html
<button type="button" id="test">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Or, in fact, move all the script code to that `script` element at the end.

Comment: Hmmm.. .Okay, i see.
But i also tried using window.onload = Hello;  That didnt work.. So the only way you can do it is by calling the function at the bottom of the body?

Comment: `window.onload = Hello;` <-- that is calling the alert function, not the one that is binding the click event....

Comment: *"JavaScript libraries such as jQuey make this more elegant..."* Have to disagree there, I don't see anything "more elegant" about enabling incorrect script placement. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't have a strong position  on that  - for small projects I usually just put it at the end of the page anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload=testFunction;
function testFunction(){
document.getElementById("test").onclick = Hello;
}
function Hello(){
    alert("Hello");
}
```

Comment: you need to load that function on window loading..have tested ..it works fine

Answer (score -1):

Just run the line in your `testFunction` always. As seen here:
https://jsfiddle.net/arugco4b/